# Notes overlap in score

Tags: vexflow

I drew the score using vexflow easyscore.

But is it because the notes are horizontally long? The problem of overlapping notes is recurring.

[image]

I can't figure out which options need to be modified with easy score.

This is my code:

```js
const { Factory, EasyScore, System } = Vex.Flow;

const vf = new Factory({
  renderer: { elementId: 'output', width: 500, height: 200 },
});

const score = vf.EasyScore();
const system = vf.System();

system
  .addStave({
    voices: [
      score.voice(score.notes('(C#4 C4)/4, (D4 Db4)/4, (D#4 D4)/4, (E4 Eb4)/4', { stem: 'up' })),
    ],
  })
  .addClef('treble')
  .addTimeSignature('4/4');

vf.draw();
```